# Passing IAM role to a Docker on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

What is the suggested way to pass IAM role to a Docker container on EC2?

I have a mlflow project running in a docker environment on EC2. 
The python code needs to read and write from S3. 
The following is the error (sometimes other types of error also indicating no s3 access from the container, for example s3 resourece not found error)

```
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (xxx) could not be found
```

To solve the s3 access issue, I already created an IAM role that allows access to the bucket.

What are the best ways to give this role to the Docker container?
Is it possible to define the role name in `Dockerfile`?

Thanks

Comment: Can your EC2 connect to the bucket without a docker? Did you edit your EC2 instance (Instance Settings ->  Attach/Replace IAM role) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ECS to run containers on your EC2 instances you can set the taskRoleArn in the Task Definition. If you are running docker on EC2 without ECS you could give the instance the role and use `--net host` and the container should use the ec2 instance's role.

Comment: Can you tell how to do this exactly? any examples please?

Answer (score -3):

I'm using docker on EC2 and I just created an Instance Profile.

If you use Console:

```
Instances -> CHOOSE YOUR INSTANCE -> Actions -> Instance Settings -> Attach/Replace IAM Role
```

If you use CloudFormation:

```
EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref EC2InstanceIAMInstanceProfile
      ...
```