# How to solve Terraform error configuring S3 Backend

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a dedicated `gitlab runner` to execute some `terraform` files so it will spin up some instances in `AWS`.

So here's the thing:
**I don't have any aws credentials (no access token etc)**

So you might think then the error is obvious. **But NO**

**Why?** - because I am only getting this error with `gitlab` `docker` executor. But not with `shell` executor.

So I have an `aws` `ec2` instance running in the same `vpc` that the other `ec2` instances will be spinning up from `terraform`.

This is working fine with `gitlab` `shell` executor. The `ec2` instance where `gitlab-runner` is installed with has `Admin` access role attached to it, so I don't have to worry about `aws` credentials.

So you might think, they you can create `aws` access token and pass it to the `docker-image` of `gitlab-runner` as `entrypoint` values in `.gitlab-ci.yaml` as below:

```
image:
  name: <my-image>
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
    - ‘PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}'
```

but **NO!!!**

**Why?** - because in my organization I don't have the access to create these access tokens. That's why I have setup the runner inside a `ec2` in the same `vpc`.

So my question is, why this is working fine when I am using the `shell` executor, but when using `docker` executor?

**My guess:** - because jobs are running inside containers in the `docker executor` - which is `docker-in-docker` and they (containers running the ci jobs) are not in the same network as `ec2`

Is that right?

Does anyone of you have a good solution for this?

Again **I must say -** This works well (i don' get the error) when using `gitlab-runner` `shell` executor as the runner is executing `shell` commands in the host machine (`EC2`) because, it is as same as executing those commands in the host itself. But in this case, jobs are executing inside the containers.

Anyone can help me, Please?

Comment: yes..seems like the network is different for the docker. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449585/passing-iam-role-to-a-docker-on-ec2

Comment: it says to use `--net host` but I don't know where to put it. Any idea?